# In R: How to loop over a dataframe and multiple matrices?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix, dataframe

Say I have a data frame with four vectors that is structured like this, but holds information on 300 countries for 31 years.

```
year<-c(1999,1999,1999,2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001)
country<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
class<-c(3,2,2,5,2,2,2,1,4)
count<-c(2,5,6,2,4,8,1,4,3)
df<-data.frame(year,city,class,count) 

  year country class count
1 1999       1     3     2
2 1999       2     2     5
3 1999       3     2     6
4 2000       1     5     2
5 2000       2     2     4
6 2000       3     2     8
7 2001       1     2     1
8 2001       2     1     4
9 2001       3     4     3
```

The value for `count` tells us how many cars there are in a certain year, country and class. In my example above, country 1 has only 2 cars in class three in 1999.

I also have 31 matrices (1 for each `year`) with `nrow=438` and `ncol=438`. The number 438 corresponds to the number of classes a car can belong to. The value of the elements represent the *distance* between the classes. This value is given.

For example: the distance between car class 1 and 8 in 1999 is 0.0016.

```
>example_input_matrix_1999[1:10,1:10]

        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]   [,8]   [,9]  [,10]
 [1,] 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000    0    0    0 0.0016 0.0000 0.0000
 [2,] 0.0000 1.0000 0.0481 0.0000    0    0    0 0.0213 0.0000 0.0000
 [3,] 0.0000 0.0481 1.0000 0.0000    0    0    0 0.0000 0.0065 0.0000
 [4,] 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000    0    0    0 0.0138 0.0000 0.0000
 [5,] 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000    1    0    0 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 [6,] 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000    0    1    0 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 [7,] 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000    0    0    1 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 [8,] 0.0016 0.0213 0.0000 0.0138    0    0    0 1.0000 0.0176 0.0067
 [9,] 0.0000 0.0000 0.0065 0.0000    0    0    0 0.0176 1.0000 0.0000
[10,] 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000    0    0    0 0.0067 0.0000 1.0000
```

Now, I want to construct a between country level measure that tells me the "average distance" between the cars in that country to the cars in other countries.

The research question is: how much do the cars in country X look like cars in country Y in terms of class in year T.

First, I start with the first year, city and class. In my example above, country 1 has only 2 cars in class three. Now I find in what classes the cars in other countries in that year are. I find 5 cars in class two for country 2 and 6 cars in class 2 for country three in 1999.

Second, I want to find the distance between class 3 and 2 in 1999, so I need to refer to the input matrix that holds the distance for that year between these classes. I find the distance between class 2 and 3 to be 0.0481.

Third, I need to multiple this distance by the product of number of cars in the two classes (in this case ten times 0.0481). I want to do this for every pair of classes between two countries. If I sum these, I have the *total distance* between any pair of countries.

Fourth, because I am interested in the *average distance*, I want to divide this value by the product of the total number of cars in country 1 and the total number of cars in country 2.

**The output of this calculation is what I am looking for, but do not know who to code this.**

Finally I want the output in 31 matrices (300*300) that has countries on the rows and columns and where the elements represent the *average distance* in terms of car classes between these countries in each year.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What does the row signify for each matrix?  Not really clear what the expected result would be.

Comment: Could you show a subset of your `matrix` and the expected result based on the `df` you showed.  For example, you can show `mat1[1:5,1:5]` where `mat1` is the first matrix.

Comment: @Frank-LA It would be helpful to see the an example of the input matrix (one of the 31) and how the rows and columns represent cars and classes, as well as the output matrix (one of the 31) and how the input matrix maps to the output matrix. I find it difficult to go from your data frame with 3 years, 3 countries, and 5 classes to 438 and 300 rows/cols.

Comment: @Richard Herron I added some data about the content and structure of the data frame. I hope that this deals with your last comment. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Frank-LA  Sorry, I couldn't link these two datasets to what you expected (which is still not clear).

Comment: @akrun, I understand. It was rather vague. I edited my question and hope it is more clear right now.

Comment: @Frank-LA It still isn't clear how to map 438x438 to 300x300. I am sure that once we understand this mapping that the aggregation process is simple, but it isn't clear to would-be answerers how you would do this mapping. It would be helpful to have a random input matrix and the operations that map it to the output matrix.

Comment: @RichardHerron Thanks for commenting! In my data frame I have all 300 countries and know exactly how many cars and in what class these are for each year. I know from the class distance input matrices how 'distant' each classes are from each other (438*438 matrix). For each country(I) in each year I want to loop over the number of cars in classes, and compare these to the number of cars in classes from country(J), find the average distance and write this distance in a 300*300 matrix for (I,J). By looping, I hope to fill the whole matrix. Makes more sense? My apologies for the vagueness.